# Setting slime-enable-evaluate-in-emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

I am using SBCL with slime, and have the following code:

```
(swank::eval-in-emacs
  '(with-current-buffer (slime-repl-buffer)
     (insert (propertize "foo" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red")))))

(print "here is some text")
```

In general, if I try to execute anything with `swank::` prefixed to it, emacs will give a security error, and this particular one tells me I need to set `slime-enable-evaluate-in-emacs` to true. Where is this value? I haven't been able to find a slime or swank config. & settings file. Thanks much.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add this to your .emacs:

```
(setq slime-enable-evaluate-in-emacs t)
```

If non-nil, the inferior Lisp can evaluate arbitrary forms in Emacs.
The default is nil, as this feature can be a security risk.